# Big <div> inside smaller <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working with a calendar, created with table. When clicking a td, I want a div to show up. This is pretty easy, but the problem is that the div will be bigger than the td, and then it expands the td's size. I want it to not affect the td's size, and being put on top of the td (in it's full size).

HTML:

```
<table *ngIf="datoer">
        <tr>
            <td 
                *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()">{{cell.text}}
                <div class="details"> </div>
            </td>            
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    }

table, td, th {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding: 5px;
    }

table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 16.6%;
    }
```

Anyone?

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Code added.

Comment: do you want it to float above the `TD`? I am not sure you mean by it will be bigger (but not affect the outer `td`) - do you want it to scroll within the `td`? please clarify

Comment: @paolo.basso99 I have no suggestions to the CSS yet. I have some CSS for other purposes, but I don't understand why you need it to help.

Comment: @ochi If I write for ex. a long text inside the div, the width of the td will increase according to the width of the div. I want to avoid the td from increasing width (and height), and instead let the div overlap several td's.

Comment: An element's size (`width`, `height`) attributes are (and can be) controlled by CSS - so you need the existing CSS to see what modifications are needed - doing so inline is poor practice

Comment: @ochi The CSS is in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

Position relative on your td

And position absolute on your div

That way when somebody hover over the certain td the div will be displayed

`td > div { position: absolute; display: none;} td:hover > div {display: block;}`

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/BjarkeH/pen/ozKxKX?editors=1100#0)

Comment: Excellent mate. Works perfectly, I'll definately use the popup. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm seems like it's only overlapping vertically, not horizontally. If the text inside the div is longer than the td's width, it continues on the next line below.

Comment: I am not sure I understand,

Comment: If I hover a cell with a long text, the text does not overlap the next cells to the right. Instead it makes a line break so it does stay inside the width of the cell.

Comment: Solved. Removed 'position: relative' from the td.

Comment: Alright glad to hear you got it solved, but I wouldn't have removed the position relative, because that's the indicator for telling what the child element should be positioned in comparison with.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're trying to overlap the div above the TD couldn't you just assign the div a higher z-index in the CSS versus the TD element? It seems like that would be the most straightforward way to accomplish what it sounds like you're asking.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Patrick Yes I know that, but the trouble is the td's width and height is increasing to fit the div, which I want to not happen. I want it to overlap several td's instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something similar to the code below.

Basically, when the mouse enters a `td` - the contents of the `data` attribute are copied onto a hidden `div` and then displayed (relative to the cursor's position)

This prevents duplicate code (i.e. inner `divs`) when not used.

See code below (only Monday and Thursday have data in it).

```js
$(function() {

  var mouseX;
  var mouseY;
  // keep track of mouse coordinates
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
  });

  $('body').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('#hiddenContent').hide();
  });

  $('td').on('mouseover', function() {
    var contentHtml = $(this).data('cal');

    if (contentHtml) { // move hidden div to mouse coordinates
      $('#hiddenContent').css({
        'top': mouseY,
        'left': mouseX
      });

      // add content and toggle
      $('#hiddenContent').text(contentHtml).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#hiddenContent {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}
td {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
    <th>Sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-cal="on mon we have many things">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td data-cal="on friday we have many things too">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="hiddenContent">
  this is hidden
</div>
```